# Property 'createVector' does not exist

Tags: typescript, p5.js

I'm trying to write some sketches using Typescript with p5.js.  I've installed p5 and @types/p5 through npm.

In my sketch I'm trying to create a Vector using the createVector method but typescript can't seem to find it. I just get the error "Property 'createVector' does not exist on type 'typeof import("local_path_stuff/node_modules/@types/p5/index.d.ts")'."

Does anyone have any recommendations for fixing this error?

```js
/// @ts-check
/// <reference path="../../node_modules/@types/p5/global.d.ts" />
import p5 from "p5";

export abstract class BaseEntity {
    protected pos: p5.Vector;
    protected id: number;
    protected entityType: number;
    constructor(id: number, entityType: number, pos?: p5.Vector){
        this.id = id;
        this.entityType = entityType;
        if(pos) {
            this.pos = pos;
        } else {
            this.pos = p5.createVector(0,0); //Error here
        }
    }
    abstract update(dt: number): void;
    abstract draw(s: p5): void
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out myself. I need to pass in an instance of a P5 type.

```js
/// @ts-check
/// <reference path="../../node_modules/@types/p5/global.d.ts" />
import type p5 from "p5";

export abstract class BaseEntity {
    protected pos: p5.Vector;
    protected id: number;
    protected entityType: number;
    constructor(s: p5, id: number, entityType: number, pos?: p5.Vector){
        this.id = id;
        this.entityType = entityType;
        if(pos) {
            this.pos = pos;
        } else {
            this.pos = s.createVector(0,0);
        }
    }
    abstract update(dt: number): void;
    abstract draw(s: p5): void
}
```